# Python Can't find the mvnc module

Tags: python, python-import, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to setup the movidius library created by intel, but I keep getting stuck when I try to import the mvnc package.

To set up mvnc I followed the directions here: [Real-time object detection with movidius](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/19/real-time-object-detection-on-the-raspberry-pi-with-the-movidius-ncs/)

and when it comes time to test if the install works, I run

> make examples

which gives this error whenever I run it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 25, in <module>
    from Models.Blob import *
  File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Models/Blob.py", line 19, in <module>
    from Controllers.MiscIO import *
  File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Controllers/MiscIO.py", line 35, in <module>
    from mvnc import mvncapi
```

So I'm wondering how it would be possible to get python to recognize the mvnc module so I can import it into any of my code. Thank you for your help!

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS in a virtual machine on a windows 10 computer

Here's the full command line output:

```
./install-opencv.sh
Installing opencv python for non-Raspbian
[sudo] password for odyssey: 
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-python)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from opencv-contrib-python)

make examples starting.
(cd examples; make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples'
make -C apps/. 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps'
make -C hello_ncs_py/. 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps/hello_ncs_py'
nothing to make, use 'make run' to run.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps/hello_ncs_py'
make -C multistick_cpp/. 
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps/multistick_cpp'

making googlenet
(cd ../../caffe/GoogLeNet; make compile; cd ../../apps/multistick_cpp; cp ../../caffe/GoogLeNet/graph ./googlenet.graph;)
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/caffe/GoogLeNet'

making prereqs
(cd ../../data/ilsvrc12; make)
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/data/ilsvrc12'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/data/ilsvrc12'

making prototxt
Prototxt file already exists

making caffemodel
caffemodel file already exists

making compile
mvNCCompile -w bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel -s 12 deploy.prototxt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mvNCCompile", line 25, in <module>
    from Models.Blob import *
  File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Models/Blob.py", line 19, in <module>
    from Controllers.MiscIO import *
  File "/usr/local/bin/ncsdk/Controllers/MiscIO.py", line 35, in <module>
    from mvnc import mvncapi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mvnc'
Makefile:80: recipe for target 'compile' failed
make[4]: *** [compile] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/caffe/GoogLeNet'
cp: cannot stat '../../caffe/GoogLeNet/graph': No such file or directory
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'googlenet' failed
make[3]: *** [googlenet] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps/multistick_cpp'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'multistick_cpp/.' failed
make[2]: *** [multistick_cpp/.] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples/apps'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'apps/.' failed
make[1]: *** [apps/.] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/odyssey/workspace/ncsdk/examples'
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'examples' failed
make: *** [examples] Error 2
```

Comment: whats the complete error? There is no error message in the trace you have provided

Comment: Sure, I added the full command line output

Comment: Did you check this, seems some modification gets rid of this issue however seems there are inherent issues with SDK for `make` operations .  https://ncsforum.movidius.com/discussion/328/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mvnc

Comment: I saw that post, but none of the comments really offer an answer to my problem. Plus, the problem they seem to be having seems to be due to a virtual enviroment, but I'm not using one

Answer (score 1):

To perform the typical installation of the NCSDK, use the following command on your host machine:

```
    git clone -b ncsdk2 http://github.com/Movidius/ncsdk && cd ncsdk && make install
```

You must enable a USB 3.0 controller and create USB whitelist filters for the virtual machine.

The USB 3.0 feature requires the VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Shut down the virtual machine

With the virtual machine selected on the VirtualBox Manager:

```
Open Settings -> USB
    Check “Enable USB Controller”
    Check “USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller”
    Add a new USB filter with Vendor ID: 03e7
        The other filter fields can be blank.
    Add a new USB filter with Vendor ID: 040e
        The other filter fields can be blank
```

Use the following command in your ncsdk directory to download necessary prerequisites and models and build all examples:

```
make examples
```